# Starting and Controlling an External Process via STDIN/STDOUT with Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to launch an external process that is to be controlled via messages sent back and forth via stdin and stdout.  Using subprocess.Popen I am able to start the process but am unable to control the execution via stdin as I need to.

The flow of what I'm trying to complete is to:

1. Start the external process
2. Iterate for some number of steps

   1. Tell the external process to complete the next processing step by writing a new-line character to it's stdin
   2. Wait for the external process to signal it has completed the step by writing a new-line character to it's stdout
3. Close the external process's stdin to indicate to the external process that execution has completed.

I have come up with the following so far:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([PathToProcess], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in xrange(StepsToComplete):
    print "Forcing step # %s" % i
    process.communicate(input='\n')
```

When I run the above code the '\n' is not communicated to the external process, and I never get beyond step #0.  The code blocks at process.communicate() and does not proceed any further.  I am using the communicate() method incorrectly?

Also how would I implement the "wait until the external process writes a new line" piece of functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

process.communicate(input='\n') is wrong.  If you will notice from the Python docs, it writes your string to the stdin of the child, then reads all output from the child until the child exits. From doc.python.org:

> Popen.communicate(input=None) Interact
>   with process: Send data to stdin. Read
>   data from stdout and stderr, until
>   end-of-file is reached. Wait for
>   process to terminate. The optional
>   input argument should be a string to
>   be sent to the child process, or None,
>   if no data should be sent to the
>   child.

Instead, you want to just write to the stdin of the child.  Then read from it in your loop.

Something more like:

```
process=subprocess.Popen([PathToProcess],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
for i in xrange(StepsToComplete):
    print "Forcing step # %s"%i
    process.stdin.write("\n")
    result=process.stdout.readline()
```

This will do something more like what you want.

Comment: Something that bit me when I first did this was that if you're only sending a few characters, you may have to flush the streams before anything is transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Twisted, by using [reactor.spawnProcess](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.spawnProcess.html) and [LineReceiver](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html).