# Python and MySQLdb warnings

Tags: python, mysql, warnings, mysql-python

I have a program that is exporting MSSQL data and importing it into MySQL. I have a function that is importing as follows:

```
def importMySql (mycursor,exportedfilename,table,delimiter):
    file_loc = str(sys.path[0] +"\\" +exportedfilename.lower()+".out").replace("\\", "\\\\")
    mycursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%s' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" %(str(file_loc), table, delimiter))
```

the cursor (MySQLdb) is raising the following warnings:

```
C:\Users\tfy\Documents\PyProj\UTL (Export, Import, RDF)\eic.py:98: Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 1194
  mycursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%s' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" %(str(file_loc), table, delimiter))
C:\Users\tfy\Documents\PyProj\UTL (Export, Import, RDF)\eic.py:98: Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 2009
  mycursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%s' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" %(str(file_loc), table, delimiter))
C:\Users\tfy\Documents\PyProj\UTL (Export, Import, RDF)\eic.py:98: Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 4793
  mycursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%s' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" %(str(file_loc), table, delimiter))
```

but I need to control the warning to only output:

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 1194
Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 2009
Warning: Data truncated for column 'DateofCharges' at row 4739
```

I have looked around and found plenty of information that illustrates hows to create custom warnings. However, not sure how I would achieve the above. I do not want to turn off the warnings, I just want to "format" them. I thought about editing the actual MySQLdb file but it is in .egg format and unable to do that. I also played around `warning.format()` but was unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is the easiest way I have found... Not sure why I did not think of this originally... but I simply suppressed the warnings issued by the cursor:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = MySQLdb.Warning)
```

I then added this code to my importMySql function:

```
mycursor.execute("SHOW WARNINGS")
warnings = mycursor.fetchall()
for i in range(len(warnings)):
    print "Warning - " +warnings[i][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

figure this out to use pprint. As the OPs solution the default warnings need be suppressed, and then add the show_warnings function, and then use the new print format.

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
import MySQLdb as mdb
from pprint import pprint

filterwarnings('ignore', category = mdb.Warning)
con = mdb.connect(...)
cur = con.cursor()
query = "Update table ..."
cur.execute(query)
con.commit()
warnings = con.show_warnings() # return in tuple type
pprint(warnings, width=100, depth=2) # width is the num of characters in each line, and depth is the level of the warnings in the tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using MySQLdb

You could monkey patch MySQLdb to achieve this:

```
import types

def warning_check(self):
    if not self._warnings:
        self.messages = ()
        return
    self.messages = self._get_db().show_warnings()
```

Then patch the Cursor object in your function like this:

```
cur._warning_check = types.MethodType(warning_check, cur)
```

Then, when you are done executing `LOAD DATA..`, you can print the messages:

```
cur.execute("LOAD DATA..")
for msg in cur.messages:
    print "Warning: {msg}".format(msg=msg[2])
```

### Using MySQL Connector/Python

Using MySQL Connector/Python, you would do something like this:

```
cnx.get_warnings = True
cur.execute("LOAD DATA..")
for msg in cur.fetchwarnings():
    print "Warning: {msg}".format(msg=msg[2])
```

(Note that you need the client flag set with the connection argument `client_flags=[mysql.connector.ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES]`)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run your mysql code in a subprocess? If so, you can use Python's [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to run the mysql code, read output from stdout and format it accordingly. For example, use `process.stdout.readline()`.

You can refer to this question: [Starting and Controlling an External Process via STDIN/STDOUT with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087799/starting-and-controlling-an-external-process-via-stdin-stdout-with-python)