# Is it possible to get the execute summary after run python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

all,

In bash, when we run a mysql query with -svve, then we can get a summary of the execution of the query as below:

```
query="update ..."
mysql -svve"$query"
```

result/summary after run the script above:

```
Query OK, 67 rows affected
Records: 67  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Bye
```

I am wondering whether we can have some thing similar after call a python mysql function as below:

```
python -c"import mysqlfunction; mysqlfunction.run_query(\"$query\")"
```

I use the python lib MySQLdb in the mysqlfunction.run_query().

Thanks very much

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html says 
python -v would print the verbose, have you tried it ?

Comment: @MiroRodozov, thanks for your reply. I tried -v after your reply. But that is for python module process, not for mysql result. I use MySQLdb in the python musqlfunction script, but can not find a option for the message in MySQLdb.

Comment: hi, all, later I use show_warnings() function in python mySQLdb , and pprint to process result of mysql query. See my solution posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394825/python-and-mysqldb-warnings/38919359#38919359.